# HP DisplayPort Dual Monitor Setup with Fedora

Tags: fedora, multi-monitor, hdmi, displayport

I have two HDMI monitors coming out of a DisplayPort adapter with dual HDMI outputs.  Right now they are cloned, but I want to extend the desktop instead of clone.  How do I do that?  The output of xrandr below.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    50.00    59.94  
1680x1050     59.88  
1600x900      60.00  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.90  
1280x800      59.91  
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      60.00  
800x600       60.32  
720x576       50.00  
720x480       60.00    59.94  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is quite an old question, but since external monitors on displayports/HDMI don't play nice with Linux I might as well try to help anyone Googling this in the future.

I use arch myself, but since you use xrandr (randr) to set up your monitors I suppose the same instructions should work.
There is very good documentation on the arch forum on using [xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr) and [multihead](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead#VGA1_right_of_HDMI1_at_fixed_resolutions) (for several monitors).

If you get an image on both external monitors than what you need to do is to use relative positioning with the keywords `--left-of`,`--right-of`,`--above` or `--below`.

You can also use absolute positioning with the keyword `--pos` when you know the resolution of your screens and want to have them at weird locations relative to each other.

To make any changes to settings in xrandr permanent you probably need to add these to a configuration file, which depends on your system. I do not know Fedora, so I am not much help here. But I am sure there are plenty of people who do.

If you use gnome there is however an easier solution. Use the screen widget in your tools menu and set the monitors to multiple screens. You can then push the "rearrange screens" button and drag them relative to each other.

I have a different issue when using my HP monitors from laptop bay displayports. I know many HP monitor users share this. Therefore, I add my solution here.

*Problem*: It will not recognize the external monitor because the resolution of the screens read in lacks the supported resolution by the screen. As a result, the monitor stays asleep/goes to sleep. And it does not help to add the resolution using xrandr.

*Solution* (work-around): In this case, the only way of getting the computer to enable the screen with the correct resolution is to boot up the computer before connecting it to the laptop bay, but **do not log in yet**. *Connect the computer to the screen through the bay before logging in*. At that time the computer recognizes the correct resolutions and all screens will work also after logging in. 
It is virtually impossible to fix after logging in with my laptop bay. Disconnecting from the bay and reconnecting does nothing. The monitor just stays asleep.

I hope this helps someone using HP monitors on Linux and a displayport/HDMI through a laptop bay.